# Can I take prescribed psychotropic Controlled drugs to UAE?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, uae, drugs, abu-dhabi

I got a job in the UAE and even have my visa. But I have been prescribed a psychotropic drug called Rexipra which has been marked as  a banned/controlled drug in the UAE.

I searched online and found some websites which say that you need to get approval from MOHAP, but outher websites say that a certified prescription is enough to take the prescribed medicines for 3 months.

I have my flight next week and I am not sure if I should take the medicines with me.

Answer (score 18):

Per the Ministry of Health, if you are a resident of the UAE (which you will be since you're working there), you *must* have a **Permit to Import Medicines for Personal Use** to import any controlled drugs.  The application takes three working days to process (possibly longer right now because it's Eid al-Fitr as I type this), so get cracking:

https://mohap.gov.ae/en/services/issue-of-permit-to-import-medicines-for-personal-use

You *really* don't want to take any risks here, the punishment for illegal drugs in the UAE are draconian.  If you can't get the permit in time, don't take the medicines, and instead book an appointment with a local doctor so you can get a new local prescription.

Comment: Hi. I am planning to not take any drugs at all as it seems too risky. Do you know how long it takes to meet a local doctor? Also, I wont have any insurance at first, do you know about the costs?

Comment: If you have the necessary permit it'll be fine, so just go ahead and apply?  You may still get it in time.

Comment: Also, I would expect that if you bring in your old prescription, any general practitioner (GP) can write you a new one on the spot.

Comment: Okay. So if I take a Prescription do I get to buy the Meds through GP's New one?  I am not sure if I should take any meds. Specially as I am from Poorer country, I may not get any approvals. But I will try to get the approval.

Comment: Also (if feasible) contact your local embassy, especially if you have a work contract there it's their job to help you out

Comment: @Hobbamok No, it's not, they'll just point you to the same page I linked above.  The process here is very clear, just apply for the permit.

Comment: @Mr.SsS If you're on medication for a mental health condition, consult your doctor before considering withdrawal.  Many have withdrawal symptoms.  Even for those that don't, if you stop taking your medication before your condition is controlled then you are at a substantial risk of relapse.  Adding the stress of starting a new job, and the stress of starting a new life in a new and very different country, and the stress of being away from your entire support network of family and friends, will significantly increase the already-high risk of a relapse.  Be super cautious here.

Comment: @Graham. Thanks for the info! I am tired of taking these medications. Doctor also said the same thing as you did. But do you have some ideas, how long I should take these medications. Its been a long 6 years since the first time I took these meds. I feel a lot better now.

Comment: @Mr.SsS That totally depends on the condition, on your current situation with regards to that condition, and the medication.  If the medication is managing an ongoing condition (e.g. bipolar) then you can't ever stop taking it; your doctor can help get the right medication and the right dosage, but you wouldn't generally be safe without it.  For more transient situations (e.g. depression) your doctor should have a plan to help you come off them when the crisis has eased.  If you don't think your doctor is any good, get a second opinion elsewhere, but you do need a doctor's advice.

Comment: @Mr.SsS - Also consider: If you feel better now, _while taking the meds_, then that doesn't mean you'd actually still feel fine without them.  Just because you're dry while standing under an umbrella doesn't mean you won't get wet if you put the umbrella away and it's still raining.  As everyone else said, don't change your meds or stop taking them without discussing with your doctor.